# python manage.py run server is not working

Tags: python, django

need help please
"...can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" Im working on windows. I am trying to run the server but  I keep getting this error. I tried every solution that is posted but no luck.  what's the solution please ? thank you

Comment: Manage.py is not in the directory. Look for manage.py then run the command.

Comment: Are you run the command `runserver` is from manage.py file  located directory ??

Comment: Yesterday I was able to run the server but today I can not for some reason that I still cant figure out. I am using pycharm terminal. –    
so I open my command prompt. 1st thing I do is pip install django 2nd django-admin startproject django_project 3rd I open pycharm and I dragged the django_project inside pycharm. 4th I write in the terminal of pycharm " python manage.py run server " but then the message comes no such file or directory. can you help me please

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` this is the command.

Comment: please type `ls` in terminal and ensure `manage.py` file is in list.

Comment: @RiyasAc Why a screenshot? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explicitly states "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc"

Comment: I did start the project, ( django-admin startproject django_project) and I dragged the file django _project to pycharm. and I can see under the file the following:  _init_.py   settings.py   urls.py  wsgi.py   manage.py   main.py ....... now when I run in the terminal  : python manage.py run server, It says it can not open file ' manage.py' no such file or directory ..... so im stuck,  I still cant run the server ? can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Navigate into the Django Project Folder where manage.py file is located and execute the same command :   python manage.py runserver

Example: Assume the project structure

```
[projectname]/
├── [appname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Navigate into the project folder i.e., cd Projectname and execute python manage.py runserver

Comment: I went by your advice but no luck. Yesterday I was able to run the server but today I can not for some reason that I still cant figure out. I am using pycharm terminal.

Comment: so I open my command prompt. 1st thing I do is pip install django      2nd django-admin startproject django_project  3rd I open pycharm and I dragged the django_project inside pycharm. 4th I write in the terminal of pycharm " python manage.py run server " but then the message comes no such file or directory

Comment: can you please help me ?

Comment: I did start the project, ( django-admin startproject django_project) and I dragged the file django _project to pycharm. and I can see under the file the following:  _init_.py   settings.py   urls.py  wsgi.py   manage.py   main.py ....... now when I run in the terminal  : python manage.py run server, It says it can not open file ' manage.py' no such file or directory ..... so im stuck,  I still cant run the server ? can you help me please

Comment: Right click the projectname and choose open in terminal. then with the flow

Comment: else post you terminal folder path: find the example below                   
 C:\Users\Master\Desktop\handbook-api>

Comment: so i right click the project name and choose open in terminal, and i was able to run the server. now after creating a blog app ( python manage.py startapp blog ) i tried to run the server again but it did not work. the following error message pop up :

Comment: File "C:\Users\Sam Iam \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.urls'
can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project folder where manage.py is and if you are using vs code you can right click and open vs code in that directory or you can copy the path and in your ide type: cd path then it should work

Comment: I did start the project, ( django-admin startproject django_project) and I dragged the file django _project to pycharm. and I can see under the file the following:  _init_.py   settings.py   urls.py  wsgi.py   manage.py   main.py ....... now when I run in the terminal  : python manage.py run server, It says it can not open file ' manage.py' no such file or directory ..... so im stuck,  I still cant run the server ? can you help me please

Comment: When you create django project using django-admin it will create a folder with your project name that you specified in that folder there will be manage.py and a folder with the same project name that nested folder contains the other files settings.py and urls.py and so on, so i think you are in that nested folder directory in pycharm terminal write ls it will show you the files in the current directory that you are in if you dont see manage.py and see urls.py and other files then do cd ..

Answer (score 0):

open your project folder and type

`cmd`

in top address bar and then press enter.then type

`python manage.py runserver`

in commandline and press enter.

Comment: I did start the project, ( django-admin startproject django_project) and I dragged the file django _project to pycharm. and I can see under the file the following:  _init_.py   settings.py   urls.py  wsgi.py   manage.py   main.py ....... now when I run in the terminal  : python manage.py run server, It says it can not open file ' manage.py' no such file or directory ..... so im stuck,  I still cant run the server ? can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project file and click on the option which says ' open in' and then click on terminal..which leads you to a 'local' command prompt. Now type py manage.py runserver..you should get the required result.